# Arithmetic overflow error in SQL Server when the result is cast to a decimal

Tags: sql-server, arithmetic-expressions

In the `SELECT` statement, I am trying to calculate a percentage with a precision of 1 decimal place.

This statement in the select statement returns an arithmetic overflow error:

```
CAST(((COUNT(TicketNbr)*100.00)/@TotalCount) AS Decimal (3,1)) END AS Percentage
```

The `COUNT(TicketNbr)` count value is 10.

The @TotalCount value is 10.

If I do not cast the result, the result is 1.0000.  But when I use the `CAST` function, the query results an arithmetic overflow error.

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the result for 10 * 100.0 / 10 is 100.0

it will required a minium of decimal(4,1) to hold the value.

You cast it as decimal(3,1) will result in the overflow error

Comment: Because `DECIMAL(3,1)` means: 3 digits **total**, of which 1 after the decimal point, so that only leaves **2 digits** before the decimal point which is *not enough* to hold a value of "100.0"